# What's the difference between fx:id and id: in JavaFX?

Tags: java, xml, javafx, scenebuilder

Maybe a really newbie's question....

I'm starting learning JavaFX in a FMXL Application using the Scene Builder, by reading this tutorials:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/fxml_tutorial.htm

So once i applied some changes, an issue with this 2 IDs came up... I might have missed or confused something about them...

Can anyone tell me in which cases they are used one or another?

Comment: `id` you use, to set a `CSS ID` to your Component, for example <Text id="welcome-text" .../> and in your Stylesheet you have something like that `.welcome-text { font-size: 16pt; }` so this will be applied to your `Text` and the `fx:id` you have to use, if you want to work with your Components in your Controller class, where you annotate them with `@FXML Text myWelcomeText`

Comment: @Patrick It's not `.welcome-text`, but `#welcome-text` in the CSS.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`id` you use to set a *CSS ID* to your Component, for example `<Text id="welcome-text" .../>` and in your stylesheet you have something like `#welcome-text { font-size: 16pt; }` so this will be applied to your `Text`.

`fx:id` you use if you want to work with your Components in your Controller class, where you annotate them with `@FXML Text myWelcomeText`.

Comment: So when we need to style the node and also want to assign an id, we must assign id and fx:id to the node?

Comment: @Fandi Currently, if only `fx:id` is assigned, that value will also be used for the `id` property. But I'm not sure if that's documented behavior or an implementation detail.

Answer (score 12):

The fx:id is the identity associated to component in fxml to build a controller, and the id is used for css.

Answer (score 7):

I took a look at an FXML document generated using the [JavaFX Scene Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen). You access controls from Java Controller with the fx:id. (edit) I stand corrected, the id does matter.

You can apply css from the FXML document like this:

```
<Slider id="css_id" fx:id="myslider" styleClass="style_name" .../>
```

(Replace slider with any control)

And Java controller interaction:

```
@FXML
Slider myslider;
```

Comment: There is a difference between a css id and a css class.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaFX `id` is used to set a CSS ID to a component. And `fx:id` is used for accessing that component in code (i.e. in a controller class). `fx:id` works like a components name.