# Getting Null Pointer Exception while removing a layer in Javafx

Tags: layout, nullpointerexception, javafx, layer

I have three layers
Root layout, home, content (rootLayout.fxml, home.fxml and content.fxml)

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(GenerateReport.class
                .getResource("/skin/rootLayout.fxml"));
        rootLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);


        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(GenerateReport.class
                .getResource("/skin/home.fxml"));
        AnchorPane homeLayout = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.getChildren().addAll(homeLayout);
        .
        .
        .
        rootLayout.getChildren().addAll(contentLayout);
```

like this I am adding content layout. In rootLayout.fxml i have a home button. My requiredment is if a user clicks home button
then i want content layout to be removed and home layout to be visible.

**content.fxml**

<AnchorPane id="myContent" ... fx:controller="com.ReportController">

**rootLayout.fxml**

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" .. fx:controller="com.ReportController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="home" onAction="#homeBtn" .../>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>

In my Controller (In all the fxml file i am pointing to the same controller) class i created

```
@FXML
private Button home;

@FXML
private AnchorPane myContent;

@FXML
protected void homeBtn(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("click! homeBtn");
    myContent.getChildren().clear();
}
```

The problem i am facing is i am getting NullPointerException. i.e.  myContent.getChildren() is returning null. Could anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between fx:id and id: in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686325/whats-the-difference-between-fxid-and-id-in-javafx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a Null Pointer Exception because Javafx doesn't associate your `myContent` with the AnchorPane stored in the fxml, and does not attach a reference to that object.

Nodes in fxml files are given their name identifiers by using `fx:id`. Note, for example, that your `@FXML private Button home` is marked in the fxml as `<Button fx:id="home"...>`.

In this case, your `@FXML AnchorPane myContent` is marked in fxml as `<AnchorPane id="myContent"...>`, not `<AnchorPane fx:id="myContent"...>`.

`id=""` is used only in CSS.