# How to keep css style for only one element

Tags: css, listview, javafx-8

I have this CSS style in my application:

```
.list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-font-size: 24px;
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 0.0% 50.0%, reflect, rgba(255,0,0,0.28) 0.0, rgba(102,243,255,0.58) 50.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 70.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 100.0);
}
.list-cell:hover {
    -fx-text-fill:linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, reflect, rgb(255,255,255) 0.0, rgb(255,255,77) 100.0);
}
```

And I apply it to my program:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/com/root/tomaszm/Design.css").toExternalForm());
```

And I would like to use this style only for one ListView node not for any other. I have problem that new ComboBox inherit this style.

I know thats probably basic thing but Im not yet familiar with CSS, and just looking for quick fix...

EDIT:

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#mainList .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: null;
    -fx-font-size: 24px;
    -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 0.0% 50.0%, reflect, rgba(255,0,0,0.28) 0.0, rgba(102,243,255,0.58) 50.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 70.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 100.0);
}
#mainList .list-cell:hover {
    -fx-text-fill:linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, reflect, rgb(255,255,255) 0.0, rgb(255,255,77) 100.0);
}
```

Application class

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/com/root/tomaszm/Design.css").toExternalForm());
```

controller class

```
listView.getStyleClass().add("mainList");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have written your css, you need to set the `css id` to your node and not a `styleclass` in your controller.

**Background**

A node can have both

- styleclass *(represented by `.styleclass {...}` )*
- css id     *(represented by `#id {...}` )*

From the JavaDocs:

> The Node class contains id, styleClass, and style variables that are
>   used in styling this node from CSS. The id and styleClass variables
>   are used in CSS style sheets to identify nodes to which styles should
>   be applied. The style variable contains style properties and values
>   that are applied directly to this node.

**Difference**

`getStyleClass().add("mainList")` sets the `styleClass` of a node and is used in the css file by declaring :

```
.mainList {
   ...
}
```

For declaring an id to a node (lets taking your example), you should use :

```
listView.setId("mainList");
```

You use the id as you have already used in the css file:

```
#mainlist{
    ...
}
```

> A `styleclass` normally targets a set of same type of nodes where as
>   `css id` targets a particular node (but it is not mandatory)

**Note :** *Do not confuse `id` and `fx:id`. Both are used for differently and have different implementations.* [For more information, click me!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686325/whats-the-difference-between-fxid-and-id-in-javafx)

Comment: works! so I see I could also just change `.mainList .list-cell { ... }` . and use  `listView.getStyleClass().add("mylist");` the same effect right?

Comment: I don't see any reasons, why you can't ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add style class to your ListView

```
   listView.getStyleClass().add("mylist");
```

your css

```
 #mylist   .list-cell {
        -fx-background-color: null;
        -fx-font-size: 24px;
        -fx-text-fill: linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 0.0% 50.0%, reflect, rgba(255,0,0,0.28) 0.0, rgba(102,243,255,0.58) 50.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 70.0, rgba(179,179,179,0.45) 100.0);
    }
  #mylist   .list-cell:hover {
        -fx-text-fill:linear-gradient( from 0.0% 0.0% to 100.0% 100.0%, reflect, rgb(255,255,255) 0.0, rgb(255,255,77) 100.0);
    }
```

You can read the doc for more explanations http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/css_tutorial/jfxpub-css_tutorial.htm

Comment: somehow it doesnt work for me... it wont load the style

Comment: still, doesnt work... see the edit. Maybe it has something to do when I change the root for scene?