# Adding css for a single node in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I'm trying to set css for a TabPane in JavaFX.
I have two TabPanes created but for one of the TabPanes I used CSS to hide the tabs (weird I know) while the other TabPane I intend on using the default css.

However when I go to apply the css, it is applying to both the nodes.
How do I fix this issue so that only one of the TabPanes use the css?

Code:

```
    tabPane.getStyleClass().add("customTab");
    tabPane.getStylesheets().add("/resources/css/TabPane.css");
```

CSS

```
.customTab{
    -fx-tab-max-height: 0 ;
}

.customTab .tab-header-area {
    visibility: hidden ;
}

.customTab .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.customTab .tab {
    -fx-background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
.customTab .detailed .tab {
    -fx-background-color: #f4f4f4;
}

.customTab .detailed .tab-header-area .tab-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: #f4f4f4;
}
```

I have also tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28610966/how-to-keep-css-style-for-only-one-element) post and using "setId()" but got the same results.

```
#customTab .tab-header-area {
    visibility: hidden ;
}
```

and

```
.customTab.tab-header-area {
    visibility: hidden ;
}
```

and

```
.customTab > .tab-header-area {
    visibility: hidden ;
}
```

Please inform me the correct way of doing this.

Thank you.

Comment: If you only call `tabPane.getStyleClass().add("customTab")` on one of the tab panes, it should work the way you want. Are you calling that on both tab panes, for some reason?

Comment: @James_D Nope, just double checked both the controller code for the class and the FXML... but I think I found out one of the reasons and might have to change the question a little bit.

The second TabPane (the one with the TabHeaderArea  visible) resides within a tab on the FIRST TabPane which has the header area hidden so I'm guessing it is inheriting it...?

Comment: Yes, that would explain it. You probably need selectors like `.customTab > .tab-header-area` and `.customTab > .tab-header.area > .tab` throughout.