# Using fx:id as CSS id in FXML

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

It seems that in FXML if you don't specify a ID (CSS) then the fx:id value is used by default. My previous understanding was the two were completely disjoint, ID for CSS and only CSS. fx:id for @FXML bindings in the controller.

This can be demonstrated with a small test - three buttons, first with ID, second with FX:ID, third with both types of ID.

```
<VBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <Button id="cssid0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button fx:id="fxid1" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
      <Button id="cssid2" fx:id="fxid2" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Using Node.lookup(cssSelector) allows selection by fx:id

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/foo.fxml"));
    Parent p = loader.load();

    System.out.println(p.lookup("#cssid0")); // => Button[id=cssid0, styleClass=button]'Button'
    System.out.println(p.lookup("#fxid1"));  // => Button[id=fxid1, styleClass=button]'Button'

    System.out.println(p.lookup("#fxid2"));  // => null (if there is a CSS ID it takes precedent)
    System.out.println(p.lookup("#cssid2")); // Button[id=cssid2, styleClass=button]'Button'

    stage.setScene(new Scene(p, 200, 200));
    stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add("/foo.css");
    stage.show();
}
```

Also CSS allows selection by the fx:ID

```
#cssid0 {
    -fx-color: red;
}
#fxid1 {
    -fx-color: green;
}
#cssid2 {
    -fx-color: blue;
}
```

This does not appear to be covered by existing question [What's the difference between fx:id and id: in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686325/whats-the-difference-between-fxid-and-id-in-javafx), Javadoc for [Node.getId()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getId--) or anywhere else I could find.

This feature is really useful as we only need to only specify a single fx:id which can be used for controllers, CSS and unit testing using test-FX.

Is it OK to use this approach or am I building assumptions on undocumented behaviour that might change in a later release? Or is it documented somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO it is partially documented in [Introduction to FXML :: Variable Resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#variable_resolution). But not so obvious at first look:

> Assigning an fx:id value to an element creates a variable in the
> document's namespace that can later be referred to by variable
> dereference attributes ...
>
> Additionally, if the object's type defines
> an "id" property, this value will also be passed to the objects
> setId() method.

It should be completed with "if object defines the idProperty and was not set already ...". Based on the related source code is in [FXMLLoader](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.java.openjfx.backport/openjfx-78-backport/1.8.0-ea-b96.1/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.java) at line around 708:

```
        // Add the value to the namespace
        if (fx_id != null) {
            namespace.put(fx_id, value);

            // If the value defines an ID property, set it
            IDProperty idProperty = value.getClass().getAnnotation(IDProperty.class);

            if (idProperty != null) {
                Map<String, Object> properties = getProperties();
                // set fx:id property value to Node.id only if Node.id was not
                // already set when processing start element attributes
                if (properties.get(idProperty.value()) == null) {
                    properties.put(idProperty.value(), fx_id);
                }
            }
            ...
        }
```

I think it is ok to build on this behavior.