# Javafx Text area disable scroll bar

Tags: java, javafx, scroll, textarea, javafx-8

At the moment, I'm making a lw interpreter for a programming language.
http://www.muppetlabs.com/~breadbox/bf/
Anyways, I'm trying to implement a text area, but I want the scroll bars to be hidden. I've looked at multiple tutorials to do this, but none of them seemed to work. Here is the code for my fxml window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<SplitPane dividerPositions="0.6231155778894473" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="interpreter.Window">
  <items>
    <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0">
         <children>
            <HBox layoutX="188.0" layoutY="81.0" prefHeight="262.0" prefWidth="599.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="-1.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button fx:id="executor" layoutX="64.0" layoutY="64.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onExecute" text="Execute" />
                        <TextField fx:id="input" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="105.0" promptText="input" />
                        <ComboBox fx:id="byteSize" layoutX="23.0" layoutY="153.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="Byte Size" />
                        <TextField fx:id="bytes" alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" layoutX="25.0" layoutY="205.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="91.0" promptText="Bytes" text="30000" />
                        <Text layoutX="39.0" layoutY="41.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Control Center" textAlignment="CENTER">
                           <font>
                              <Font size="17.0" />
                           </font>
                        </Text>
                        <Text layoutX="122.0" layoutY="222.0" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Bytes" />
                        <Line endX="100.0" layoutX="98.0" layoutY="261.0" startX="-100.0" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>



                    <TextArea fx:id="errorLog" disable="true" editable="false" prefHeight="262.0" prefWidth="38.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #ff0000" />
                     //this is the one where I want the scroll bars hidden



                  <TextArea fx:id="code" prefHeight="262.0" prefWidth="361.0" promptText="Code" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0">
         <children>
             <TextArea fx:id="output" disable="true" editable="false" layoutX="76.0" layoutY="-60.0" prefHeight="166.0" prefWidth="598.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
  </items>
</SplitPane>
```

I have it specified which one I want to hide the scroll bar's of. Does anybody have any insight to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by setting the horizontal+vertical scrollbar policies on the inner ScrollPane. I'm currently unsure if this can be done via FXML or Java API, however it can be achieved via CSS.

See [CSS guide on ScrollPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scrollpane)

```
#errorLog .scroll-pane {
    -fx-hbar-policy: never;
    -fx-vbar-policy: never;
}
```

This assumes the CSS sub-structure of TextArea, but this is well-defined in the [official CSS gudie for TextArea](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#text-area)

```
scroll-pane — ScrollPane
    content — Region
```

If you're not using CSS already, you'll need to define a CSS file and add it to the Scene or FXML. Information on how to do this can be found in [Styling UI Controls with CSS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/apply-css.htm).

Comment: @Adam it seems you use `fx:id` in css file ,but we define an `id` for `TextArea`

Comment: If you don't specify an id the fx:id is used. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29405658/using-fxid-as-css-id-in-fxml

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to keep your need.

**By using Css :** in this CSS i suppose that `error` is `id` of `TextArea`

**Fxml :**

```
<TextArea id="error" fx:id="errorLog" disable="true" editable="false" prefHeight="262.0" prefWidth="38.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #ff0000" />
```

**CSS :**

```
#error .scroll-pane {
    -fx-hbar-policy: never;
    -fx-vbar-policy: never;
}
```

**or**

```
#error .scroll-pane{
    -fx-padding:0

}
```

These styles give you the same result.

**By using FXML :**
I added `wrapText="true"`

```
  <TextArea id="error" fx:id="errorLog" disable="true" editable="false" prefHeight="262.0" prefWidth="38.0" style="-fx-text-fill: #ff0000" wrapText="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent repeating links to the css all over my project, I extended the TextArea to create a very simple 'vertical-scroll' only TextArea object. I attached the css to the object itself. The vertical scrollbar is visible even when unnecessary because I like it that way. To only show when needed, you can change 'always' to 'as-needed' in the css call to vbar-policy.

I also added a bit of padding to centre the text vertically, although this will obviously need to change with a different font size

```
package sample.controls;

import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

public class VertOnlyTextArea extends TextArea {

    public VertOnlyTextArea(){
        setWrapText(true);
        getStylesheets().add("/css/vertOnlyTextArea.css");
    }
}
```

in the css directory...  vertOnlyTextArea.css

```
.text-area .scroll-pane {
    -fx-hbar-policy: never;
    -fx-vbar-policy: always;
}
.text-area .content{
    -fx-padding: 8 0 0 8;
}
```

hope this helps