# JavaFX compile error

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am new to JavaFX and am not sure what is going wrong here. Been trying to figure it out for hours. Please help me figure out where I went wrong!

Error Trace

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7533 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\alloy.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\annotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm-all.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm-commons.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm-tree-3.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\asm4-all.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\automaton.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\batik.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\boot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\cglib-2.2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\cli-parser-1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-codec-1.8.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-httpclient-3.1-patched.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\commons-net-3.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\ecj-4.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\extensions.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\fluent-hc-4.3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\forms_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\freemarker.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\fxHelpBrowser.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\groovy-all-2.3.9.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\gson-2.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\guava-17.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\httpclient-4.3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\httpcore-4.3.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\httpmime-4.3.6.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\icons.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea-jsp-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\ideax.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\isorelax.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jasper21_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jasper2_rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\javac2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jaxen-1.1.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jayatana-1.2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jcip-annotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jdkAnnotations.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jdom.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jettison-1.3.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jgoodies-common-1.2.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jgoodies-forms.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jgoodies-looks-2.4.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jh.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jing.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jna-utils.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jna.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jps-launcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jps-model.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jps-server.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch-0.1.51.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.connector-factory.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.core.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.pageant.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.sshagent.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.usocket-jna.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsch.agentproxy.usocket-nc.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsr166e.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jsr173_1.0_api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\junit-4.11.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\jzlib-1.1.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\log4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\markdown4j-2.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\markdownj-core-0.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\microba.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\miglayout-swing.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\nanoxml-2.2.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\nekohtml-1.9.14.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\netty-all-4.1.0.Beta4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\optimizedFileManager.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\oromatcher.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\picocontainer.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\protobuf-2.5.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\proxy-vole_20131209.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\pty4j-0.4.15.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\purejavacomm.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\resolver.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\rhino-js-1_7R4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\rngom-20051226-patched.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\sanselan-0.98-snapshot.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\serviceMessages.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\servlet-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\swingx-core-1.6.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\trang-core.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\trove4j.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\trove4j_src.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\util.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\velocity.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\winp-1.21-patched.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xbean.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xerces.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xml-apis.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xmlrpc-2.0.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xpp3-1.1.4-min.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\xstream-1.4.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\yjp-controller-api-redist.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\gradle-javaee.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\IntelliLang-javaee.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\javaee-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\JavaEE\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\PersistenceSupport\lib\persistence-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\PersistenceSupport\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\database-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\jdba.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\DatabaseTools\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\CSS\lib\css-openapi.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\CSS\lib\resources_en.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\uml\lib\diagram-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-aop.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-api.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-eclipse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\Spring\lib\spring-web.jar;C:\Users\Ethan\workspace\CSC 275 Lab 8\out\production\CSC 275 Lab 8" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain Lab8
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:875)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$147(LauncherImpl.java:157)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$1/815033865.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Ethan/workspace/CSC%20275%20Lab%208/out/production/CSC%20275%20Lab%208/Lab8Layout.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2595)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3208)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3169)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3142)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3118)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3098)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3091)
    at Lab8.start(Lab8.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$153(LauncherImpl.java:821)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/2020077337.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$166(PlatformImpl.java:323)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/834634352.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$164(PlatformImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/1656466025.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$165(PlatformImpl.java:291)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/1045693783.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(WinApplication.java:102)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$38/891996806.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Brains.initialize(Brains.java:34)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2542)
    ... 22 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Main Class

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Lab8 extends Application {

    public static void main(String[]args){
        launch(args);
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Lab8Layout.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Student Interface");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 700,700));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Controller Class (called Brains)

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Brains implements Initializable {

    @FXML public TableView<Student> studentTable;
    ObservableList<Student> studentArray = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    //First Name Column
    public TableColumn<Student,String> firstNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("First Name");
    //Last Name Column
    @FXML TableColumn<Student,String> lastNameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Last Name");
    //Major Column
    @FXML TableColumn<Student,String> majorColumn = new TableColumn<>("Major");
    //GPA Column
    @FXML TableColumn<Student,Double> gpaColumn = new TableColumn<>("GPA");
    //UIN Column
    @FXML TableColumn<Student,Integer> uinColumn = new TableColumn<>("UIN");
    //Net ID Column
    @FXML TableColumn<Student,Integer> netIDColumn = new TableColumn<>("Net ID");
    //Age Column
    @FXML TableColumn<Student,Integer> ageColumn = new TableColumn<>("Age");
    //Gender Column
    @FXML TableColumn<Student,String> genderColumn = new TableColumn<>("Gender");

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
        studentTable.setItems(studentArray);

        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        majorColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("major"));
        gpaColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gpa"));
        uinColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("uin"));
        netIDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("netID"));
        ageColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("age"));
        genderColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("gender"));

    }

    public void deleteStudent() {
        Student selectedStudent = studentTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();


    }

}
```

Student Class

```
import javafx.beans.property.*;

public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String major;
    private double gpa;
    private int uin;
    private int netID = 0;
    private int age;
    private String gender;
    public static int counter = 1;

    public Student(String newFirstName, String newLastName, String newMajor, double newGpa, int newUin, int newAge, String newGender){
        firstName = newFirstName;
        lastName = newLastName;
        setMajor(newMajor);
        setGpa(newGpa);
        setUin(newUin);
        setAge(newAge);
        setGender(newGender);
        netID = counter++;
    }
    public Student(String newFirstName, String newLastName, int newNetID, String newMajor, double newGpa, int newUin, int newAge, String newGender){
        firstName = newFirstName;
        lastName = newLastName;
        setMajor(newMajor);
        setGpa(newGpa);
        setUin(newUin);
        netID = newNetID;
        setAge(newAge);
        setGender(newGender);
        this.netID = counter++;
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public int getID(){
        return netID;
    }
    public String getMajor() {
        return major;
    }
    public void setMajor(String major) {
        this.major = major;
    }
    public double getGpa() {
        return gpa;
    }
    public void setGpa(double gpa) {
        this.gpa = gpa;
    }
    public int getUin() {
        return uin;
    }
    public void setUin(int uin) {
        this.uin = uin;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {this.gender = gender; }
}
```

FXML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Brains">
   <top>
      <VBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <MenuBar>
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                  <items>
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Save" />
                        <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Load Students" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="595.0">
               <children>
                  <TextField minWidth="80.0" promptText="First Name">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField minWidth="80.0" promptText="Last Name">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <opaqueInsets>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </opaqueInsets>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField minWidth="80.0" promptText="Major">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField minWidth="20.0" promptText="GPA">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField promptText="UIN">
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField minWidth="20.0" promptText="Age">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <TextField minWidth="30.0" promptText="Gender">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </padding>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </TextField>
                  <Pane prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="97.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                  <Button minWidth="85.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Student" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
               </padding>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="10.0" top="3.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
   <center>
      <TableView id="studentTable" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn text="First Name" id="firstNameColumn"/>
          <TableColumn text="Last Name" id="lastNameColumn" />
          <TableColumn text="Major" id="majorColumn" />
          <TableColumn text="GPA" id="gpaColumn" />
          <TableColumn text="UIN" id="uinColumn" />
          <TableColumn text="Age" id="ageColumn" />
          <TableColumn text="Gender" id="genderColumn" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <VBox BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <HBox spacing="5.0">
               <children>
                  <Button id="deleteButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#deleteStudent" text="Delete Student" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
               </padding>
            </HBox>
            <TextField editable="false" text="Status Bar" />
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

More often then not, the stack trace is telling you what's wrong:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

and it's even nice enough to tell you where:

> at Brains.initialize(Brains.java:34)

My guess is that line 34 is `studentTable.setItems(studentArray);` and studentTable is null when this code is run.

In your Brains class all the other fields are initialised, but studentTable is not. Try initialising it in a similar way to the other fields to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Thank you that worked. That's a helluva stack trace and I haven't seen something that complicated before. I appreciate your help.

Comment: That's not how JavaFX works. `FXMLLoader` takes care of loading the fxml file, finds the controller marked with `fx:controller`, creates an instance of that class, injects the objects marked with `fx:id` and annotated with `@FXML` and finally calls `initialize()`. So there's no need to initialize any of the annotated fields.

Comment: As @JoséPereda points out, this answer is not correct, and if you follow the advice in the answer it will lead to unexpected behavior later: in particular the fields you are using in your controller class are not the ones defined in the FXML (and consequently not the ones appearing in your UI). Please delete this answer: it is misleading.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it work *properly* you need:

1. Set `fx:id` in all the references in the FXML file that you then annotate with `@FXML`. You are using `id` instead. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686325/whats-the-difference-between-fxid-and-id-in-javafx).
2. Remove `public` from `studentTable`
3. Remove *all* the initializations on `Brains`. They are done *automatically*, thanks to the annotations. Read any of these tutorials:

   - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html
   - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/

But, in a nutshell, `FXMLLoader` takes care of loading the fxml file, finding the controller marked with `fx:controller`, and creating an instance of that class, injecting the objects marked with `fx:id` and annotated with `@FXML` and finally calling `initialize()`.

4. You are missing `netIDColumn` on the FXML.
5. Annotate `deleteStudent()` with `@FXML`.

Now it will run without problems.

Then I suggest you using properties on `Student`, like `StringProperty`. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522130/javafx-properties-wrapping-bean).