# JavaFX iteration with .lookup

Tags: for-loop, javafx, lookup

I am trying to make a minigame on JavaFX but I am encountering an issue where it says "currentPlayerBox" is null; it is meant to be a variable in a for loop that goes through the player areas' components to make sure they are reset for each player (1-4); here is the code:

```
for (int i=1; i < 5; i++){
            Pane currentPlayerBox = (Pane) root.lookup("player" + i + "Box");
            TextArea playerTextArea = (TextArea) currentPlayerBox.lookup("player" + i + "TextArea");
            ImageView playerImgWin = (ImageView) currentPlayerBox.lookup("player" + i + "WinImg");
            ImageView playerImgLose = (ImageView) currentPlayerBox.lookup("player" + i + "LoseImg");
            playerTextArea.clear();
            playerImgWin.setOpacity(0);
            playerImgLose.setOpacity(0);
            currentPlayerBox.getChildren().forEach (button -> button.setDisable(true));
            currentPlayerBox.setVisible(false);
           }
```

This does work if I use the actual fx:id manually; like player1Box, player2Box; but it returns null if I use `Pane currentPlayerBox = (Pane) root.lookup("player" + i + "Box")`; am I using this method wrong? Can I even do this or do I have to go 1 by 1 manually? I can post the FXML code if it is needed; but I am basically just trying to lookup some Panes inside an AnchorPane with no other parent in between. And yes, the fx:id of the AnchorPane is just "root" triplechecked that.

Comment: why do you use lookup at all (vs. keeping modeling the sync between nodes and your game state, or at least keeping references)? While possible, it's a fall-back tool usually. Anyway, [mcve] please - mind the __M__!, nothing unrelated while still runnable as-is and demonstrating what _exactly_ you are doing and how it's not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are setting an id, then you need to lookup by prepending the `#` to your string. On the other hand if you are looking for a style class then you need to prepend with `.`

So I believe try changing the code to below and check :

```
for (int i=1; i < 5; i++){
            Pane currentPlayerBox = (Pane) root.lookup("#player" + i + "Box");
            TextArea playerTextArea = (TextArea) currentPlayerBox.lookup("#player" + i + "TextArea");
            ImageView playerImgWin = (ImageView) currentPlayerBox.lookup("#player" + i + "WinImg");
            ImageView playerImgLose = (ImageView) currentPlayerBox.lookup("#player" + i + "LoseImg");
            playerTextArea.clear();
            playerImgWin.setOpacity(0);
            playerImgLose.setOpacity(0);
            currentPlayerBox.getChildren().forEach (button -> button.setDisable(true));
            currentPlayerBox.setVisible(false);
           }
```

Out of topic, please  also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686325/whats-the-difference-between-fxid-and-id-in-javafx) to have a quick overview of id(s) and see if you are using it correctly.